# Am I calling this function wrong?

Tags: c, function, structure

I am writing a program to figure out the elapsed time between two given times.

For some reason, I am getting the error: expected identifier or 'C' in regards to my elapsedTime function prototype before my main function.

I have tried moving it around the program and it doesn't make a difference if I locate it after t1 and t2 have been declared. What's the problem?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time
{
  int seconds;
  int minutes;
  int hours;
};

struct elapsedTime(struct time t1, struct time t2);

int main(void)
{

    struct time t1, t2;

    printf("Enter start time: \n");
    printf("Enter hours, minutes and seconds respectively: ");
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &t1.hours, &t1.minutes, &t1.seconds);

    printf("Enter stop time: \n");
    printf("Enter hours, minutes and seconds respectively: ");
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &t2.hours, &t2.minutes, &t2.seconds);

    elapsedTime(t1, t2);

    printf("\nTIME DIFFERENCE: %d:%d:%d -> ", t1.hours, t1.minutes, t1.seconds);
    printf("%d:%d:%d ", t2.hours, t2.minutes, t2.seconds);
    printf("= %d:%d:%d\n", differ.hours, differ.minutes, differ.seconds);

    return 0;
}

struct elapsedTime(struct time t1, struct time t2)
{
    struct time differ;

    if(t2.seconds > t1.seconds)
    {
        --t1.minutes;
        t1.seconds += 60;
    }

    differ.seconds = t2.seconds - t1.seconds;

    if(t2.minutes > t1.minutes)
    {
        --t1.hours;
        t1.minutes += 60;
    }

    differ.minutes = t2.minutes - t1.minutes;
    differ.hours = t2.hours - t1.hours;

    return differ;
}
```

Comment: What's that: `struct elapsedTime(struct time t1, struct time t2);`? `struct` is not a valid type.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It's meant to be a function declaration. The tag `time` after the `struct` keyword is missing.

Comment: For future reference, you should copy-and-paste the exact error message into your question, including the line number it refers to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function doesn't properly define a return type:

```
struct elapsedTime(struct time t1, struct time t2);
```

`struct` by itself is not enough to define the return type.  You need the struct name as well:

```
struct time elapsedTime(struct time t1, struct time t2);
```

You also need to assign the return value of the function to something:

```
struct time differ = elapsedTime(t1, t2);
```

With that working, your logic for "borrowing" when doing the difference is backwards:

```
if(t1.seconds > t2.seconds)     // switched condition
{
    --t2.minutes;               // modify t2 instead of t1
    t2.seconds += 60;
}

differ.seconds = t2.seconds - t1.seconds;

if(t1.minutes > t2.minutes)     // switched condition
{
    --t2.hours;                 // modify t2 instead of t1
    t2.minutes += 60;
}
```

As is, if `t1` is after `t2`, the hour will be negative.  If you assume this means the end time is the following day, you add 24 to hours:

```
if(t1.hours > t2.hours)
{
    t2.hours+= 24;
}

differ.hours= t2.hours - t1.hours;
```

Comment: Sorry, borrowing?

My code works right now (after the function declaration and call fix) , thank you...

as long as the second time entered is not past midnight, otherwise it thinks it's back in time and outputs a minus value.

Comment: @MattCleary Borrowing is when a subtraction of two digits (or groups of digits) results in a negative value and you need to add the value of the next digit instead.  That's what you're doing when you add 60 and subtract 1.  Because you're subtracting `t1` from `t2`, you need to check if the `t1` value is larger and if so do the borrow on `t2`, not the other way around like you're doing now.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I switched `if(t2.seconds > t1.seconds)` to `if(t1.seconds > t2.seconds)` and then recompiled and then run the program. Now if t1 is '17:52:13' and t2 is '17:52:11', the output is `TIME DIFFERENCE: 17:52:13 -> 17:52:11 = 0:1:-62`

If I left it as is, I get a problem but the other way around, when t2 > t1

Comment: @MattCleary Besides switching the conditional, you need to modify `t2` instead of `t1`.  Then with the input you mentioned the output is `-1:59:58`.

Comment: @MattCleary If you start time is after your end time and you don't account for date wraparound, you'll get something like that.  If you assume that start > end means wraparound, then add 24 to `t2.hours` and you'll get `23:59:58`.